# Adf column filter: which format does ADF use to generate the where clause in the VO's query?

Tags: oracle, filter, oracle-adf

*TLDR; is there a way to understand at runtime which format is ADF using for dates behind the scenes? In particular the format used to render dates in dynamically generated sql code?*

In the Oracle ADF Application I'm working on there are several table filters (by that I mean the field over the column in which I can write text/number/dates to query the table).

Filtering this way, the framework modifies the query of the View Object, adding the appropriate where clause. On the page there's also a button "Select all" that allows me to select all the data that's rendered in the table (there is a selection checkbox).

In the specific case, the query from the VO is used to aim two different goals:

- update the rendered data in the table
- if I press the "select all" button a function in the backend database is called (callable statement calling the function), passing as a parameter the query.

The first task is successfully reached (as the table is visually updated), but we had an issue with the second one.
The backend function uses the query to select all the extracted data (as iterating in ADF with java would be too slow).
The problem is that the where clause isn't correctly generated for the backend database (which is also oracle).

Basically the generated WHERE clause (which was added to VO's query automatically by the framework) was

```sql
WHERE record_date = '2020-10-12'
```

which I had to change to

```sql
WHERE record_date = to_date('2020-10-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

in order to have it correctly executed by the Oracle Db.

So now it's working (yay), but my concern is: **isn't it dangerous to assume the date format will be 'YYYY-MM-DD' on every application's instance?**

I think this 'YYYY-MM-DD' is the format in which ADF is managing dates (as the value is written as '2020-10-12' in the query).

**But is there a way to understand at runtime which format is ADF using for dates behind the scenes?** Or does it always use 'YYYY-MM-DD', or am I completely off-road and the storage format is another and I should ask which format does it use to render dates? But dates on page are visually rendered in another way :/

Sorry for my lack of expertise and have a nice day!

**Update**

The value of the query field, which I'm getting by calling

```java
this.getNamedWhereClauseParams().getAttribute('vc_temp_1');
```

is of class

```java
oracle.jbo.domain.Date
```

and by printing it I obtain the date in format YYYY-MM-DD.

Would it be possible that the framework was simply using Date.toString?
This would raise another question: how can I be sure of the pattern used by Date.toString? The documentation isn't clear about it (and it says that it should be used only in development, so this is quite a remote scenario).

Comment: Or maybe there is a way to add some behaviour (through some kind of extension / override) to the automatic generation of these where clauses

Comment: What exact JDev version do you use?

Comment: @TimoHahn 11.1.2.1.0 (unfortunately I'm forced to use this version because of the project)

Answer (score 0):

What you named 'Filter' is called 'Query by Example' or QBE in short. See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b31974/web_search_bc.htm#ADFFD1756) for more info.

You can change the query passed to the server using a bean method. Look at e.g. [JDev 12.2.1.3: Multi select component table filter](https://tompeez.wordpress.com/2019/03/17/jdev-12-2-1-3-multi-select-component-table-filter/) for a sample.

Using dates in ADF is always dependent on the current user's settings. If the user don'T use a specific locale the default is 'yyyy-mm-dd'. This can be changed at different points, starting by the entity objects, view objects a,d finally in the UI by using converters.

The best way to use dates depends on the use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimoHahn, you're like a lighthouse in this tempest this framework is for me (at the moment). Definetly going to read all the material you pointed to.

Comment: so I suppose there should be some kind of class managing this kind of localization data (like dates format) and that this class should expose an interface to allow me, from the different components you named (VO, EO...), to change the current locale. But I guess, if it was that easy, I would have found it by now... So I must be wrong

Comment: @gBrugna You can simply change the format in your EO or VO, Go to attribute > Select your date attribute > UI Hint > Format Type : Simple Date > Format : Whatever format you want